# When data read from memory is erroneous how can we determine whether it is a read fault or write fault?

Tags: memory, memory-management

After a lot of Googling, I've found that the CRC check determines whether the memory is erroneous or not. But I want to find out whether there is an error during the read or write cycle specifically. How can I find that out?

Comment: Read it twice? If it fails AGAIN, it's almost definitely an error in writing rather than reading.

Comment: @DanRedux: I don't want to troubleshoot. I want answer! :)